# Keep getting Access Denied when connecting to BigQuery with R

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, tidyverse, bigrquery

I am very new to GCP and BigQuery and I am trying to query a simple dataset that I have uploaded on Google BigQuery by using R. In the IAM settings, I am listed as an "BigQuery Admin", "BigQuery Data Owner" and "Owner."

I can also query the dataset using the console, but every time I keep getting an

`access denied, User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project ABCD`

Here is my code:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("bigrquery")
bq_auth(use_oob = TRUE)


# Store the project id
projectid = "ABCD"

# Set your query
sql <- "SELECT * FROM test.testtable"

# Run the query and store the data in a dataframe
mydf <- query_exec(sql, projectid, use_legacy_sql = FALSE)

# Print the query result
mydf
```

All the sources I have found so far tell me to activate the setting for Big Query in the IAM settings - but I have already done it, so I am at a loss on what to do further. Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definetly seems to be a permission issue.
Can you make sure that this program is using your credentials not some other service account credentials?

If you are running from your laptop, you can run `gcloud auth list` to find out the credential in use.

Comment: I was being stupid, I had the wrong projectID (because the full name is not shown on the top left of the google console online). Thanks for the help in any case! For future reference - Where can I run this function, in the google SDK? ( I am using Windows)

Comment: project_name and project_id are confusing at the start so no worries.
Can you elaborate your google SDK related question more?

Comment: Thank you. You said to run `gloud auth list`, my question was to run it where - at the end I ran it in the cmd and it worked. Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was really dumb. The project name is a combination of letters and numbers, but this on the top left of the cloud console only the letters are being shown. I had forgotten to put the numbers in the projectId and this is why it was not working (I was not referring to the proper project).

Hope that saves someone else the hassle!

Comment: project_name and project_id are two different thing in GCP and suggest you always use project_id as it is a unique id